# How do I add CSS classes to all the form elements?

Tags: theming, forms

How can I add the same CSS class (*form__text*) to form elements in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [`template_preprocess_form_element`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21form.inc/function/template_preprocess_form_element/8.9.x) something like:

```
use Drupal\Component\Utility\Html;
function [YOURTHEME]_preprocess_form_element(&$variables) {
  $input_types = ['search', 'textfield', 'password'];
  $type = $variables['element']['#type'] ?? NULL;
  if (in_array($type, $input_types)) {
    $variables['element']['#attributes']['class'][] = Html::cleanCssIdentifier('form__text');
  }
}
```

**Update**
If the below doesn’t work try the following using `hook_preprocess`:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess().
 */
function [YOURTHEME]_preprocess(&$variables, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'input') {
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = Html::cleanCssIdentifier('form__text');
  }
}
```

**To exclude submit button ?**
change the condition to `$hook == 'input' && $variables['element']['#type'] !== 'submit'` instead of `$hook == 'input'`

Comment: It doesn't work for me

Comment: https://www.thirdandgrove.com/insights/theming-form-elements-drupal-8/ check this out

Comment: Thank you. It works. But how to exclude submit button?

Comment: you can easily overwrite to not load the css for the submit button despite the effort on overwriting the button, I would go with that route